# WebRTC Multiple Peer connection video is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, video, webrtc

So I found a way to make a peer connection multiple times by a lot..but I can't make the video work although there is no error shown...

UPDATE: [DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-fermi-o1rz0s?file=/src/index.js) but this demo is not allow working localStream so try it in your own browser index.html

First let say we have this html file

```
     // This one is for multiple videos
    <div class="item-videos">
         //This first video is a start video
        <video id="video1" playsinline autoplay muted></video>

        //This is join videos
    </div>

    <div>
        <button id="start"> Start </button>
        <button id="join"> Join </button>
        <button id="hangup"> Hang Up </button>
    </div>
```

First I will takes the initial inputs for starter in script.js

```
        let containers = document.querySelector('.item-videos');

        const startButton = document.querySelector('#start')
        const joinButton = document.querySelector("#join")

        const video1 = document.querySelector('video#video1');

        let localStream;

        // This is the RTCPeerConnections arrays.
        let pcLocals = [];
        let pcRemotes = [];

        const offerOptions = {
            offerToReceiveAudio: 1,
            offerToReceiveVideo: 1
        };

        const servers = {
            iceServers: [
                {
                urls: ['stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302', 'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302'],
                },
            ],
            iceCandidatePoolSize: 10,
        };
```

And then let say first we will start our call server..which will be created.
So now we will make a start click then our code

```
...
        function gotStream(stream) {
            console.log('Received local stream');
            video1.srcObject = stream;
            localStream = stream;
            joinButton.disabled = false;
        }

        function start() {
            console.log('Requesting local stream');
            startButton.disabled = true;
            navigator.mediaDevices
                .getUserMedia({
                    audio: true,
                    video: true
                })
                .then(gotStream)
                .catch(e => console.log('getUserMedia() error: ', e));
        }
        startButton.addEventListener("click",start)
```

Now this is for join button in the server...let say I have `let count = 0`
and I will `createElement` each video I click the button
So our code for the join button click is

```
        let count = 0;
        joinButton.addEventListener("click",() => {
            count += 1

            //Creating Video Element
            const addVideo = document.createElement('video')
            
            addVideo.setAttribute('id',`video${count + 1}`)
            addVideo.setAttribute('class',`try-${count + 1}`)

            // Here I believe this part was my error where in the video is set up yet for the RTCPeerConnection functions. 
            containers.appendChild(addVideo)

            const videoCall = containers.querySelectorAll('video')[count]
            
            // Here I will create RTCPeerConnections and push it in the pcLocals and pcRemotes;
            const init_localStreams = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
            const init_remoteStreams = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
            
            pcLocals.push(init_localStreams)
            pcRemotes.push(init_remoteStreams)

            console.log(pcLocals)    
            console.log(pcRemotes)  
            
            //Here I'm passing the stream videos in RTCPeer Arrays...
            pcRemotes[count - 1].ontrack = (ev) => {

                function gotRemoteStream(e,video,idx) {
                    if (video.srcObject !== e.streams[0]) {
                        video.srcObject = e.streams[0]
                        console.log(`pc${idx+1}: received remote stream`);
                    }
                }
                gotRemoteStream(ev,videoCall,count - 1)

            }

            //Here I'm passing the tracks of the video in each locals
            localStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => 
            {
                pcLocals[count - 1].addTrack(track, localStream)
            });

            function onAddIceCandidateSuccess() {
                console.log('AddIceCandidate success.');
            }

            function onAddIceCandidateError(error) {
                console.log(`Failed to add ICE candidate: ${error.toString()}`);
            }

            function handleCandidate(candidate, dest, prefix, type) {
                dest.addIceCandidate(candidate)
                    .then(onAddIceCandidateSuccess, onAddIceCandidateError);
                console.log(`${prefix}New ${type} ICE candidate: ${candidate ? candidate.candidate : '(null)'}`);
            }

            function iceCallbackRemote(e,local_) {
                handleCandidate(e.candidate,local_,`pc${count}: `, 'remote')
            }

            function iceCallbackLocal(e,remote_) {
                handleCandidate(e.candidate,remote_,`pc${count}: `, 'local')
            }

            pcLocals[count - 1].onicecandidate = (ev) => {
                iceCallbackRemote(ev,pcLocals[count - 1])
            }

            pcRemotes[count - 1].onicecandidate = (ev) => {
                iceCallbackLocal(ev,pcRemotes[count - 1])
            }


            function gotDescriptionRemote(desc) {
                pcRemotes[count-1].setLocalDescription(desc);
                // console.log(`Answer from pc1Remote\n${desc.sdp}`);
                pcLocals[count-1].setRemoteDescription(desc);
            }

            function gotDescriptionLocal(desc) {
                pcLocals[count-1].setLocalDescription(desc);
                // console.log(`Answer from pc1Remote\n${desc.sdp}`);
                pcRemotes[count-1].setRemoteDescription(desc);
            
                pcRemotes[count-1].createAnswer().then(gotDescriptionRemote,onCreateSessionDescriptionError)
            }

            function onCreateSessionDescriptionError(error) {
                console.log(`Failed to create session description: ${error.toString()}`);
            }

            pcLocals[count - 1].
                createOffer(offerOptions)
                .then(gotDescriptionLocal, onCreateSessionDescriptionError)

        })
```

I'm somehow doubt my if my video was not to pass yet before the RTCPeerConnection operations happening..I don't know if where my errors here... I just tried to make a multiple peerconnection that was documentary here at [WEBRTC TUTORIAL](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/multiple/)

Comment: As the video is basically just the display output for the stream, i doubt that this is the reason for it not working. You should propably not identify your peerConnections by "count", as your whole logic will break if you press the button multiple times in a short period of time.

Comment: oh but it is push in the pcLocals and pcRemotes also, and also PeerConnections is working very well because it can print the `sdp` and other stuff so it normally function the array Peerconnections.

Comment: Okay, first things first: Do your peerConnections actually connect? You can check by tracking `peerConnection.connectionstatechange` Events and checking peerConnection.connectionState. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/connectionstatechange_event for more info.

Comment: Umm..NickG I don't know how deeply info this is...but can you make an example to it? I try it and it give me "unknown" which you directed as you said...You can copy the code...just use as normal html with javascript also maybe you can get more idea about it cuz I'm lost....

Comment: You can just do:
`const init_localStreams = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
init_localStreams.onconnectionstatechange(() => {
console.info("Connected state of peerConnection is: " + init_localStreams.connectionState);
})
` to track your peerconnection connected state. If your code and server are working properly the connectionState should change to "connected".

Comment: It says `Connected state of peerConnection is: connecting` as you said...

Comment: sir @NickG check this Codesandbox I made so you can have clear understanding of what I supposed to do https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-fermi-o1rz0s?file=/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked at you codesandbox code and found two issues:

1. The playback of your created video is never started
2. Your icecandidates are set on the wrong peerconnection

To adress the first problem, you need to start your playback either with autoplay or by starting it with `addVideo.play()`. For the autoplay solution, you can simply add:

```
  addVideo.setAttribute("autoplay", true);
  addVideo.setAttribute("playsinline", true);
```

To address the second problem, you need to change the passed peerconnections in the `onicecandidate` event handlers:

```
  pcLocals[count - 1].onicecandidate = (ev) => {
    //old: iceCallbackRemote(ev, pcLocals[count - 1]);
    //new:
    iceCallbackRemote(ev, pcRemotes[count - 1]);
  };

  pcRemotes[count - 1].onicecandidate = (ev) => {
    //old: iceCallbackRemote(ev, pcRemotes[count - 1]);
    //new:
    iceCallbackLocal(ev, pcLocals[count - 1]);
  };
```

The ice candidates need to be exchanged, meaning, ice candidates gathered by local must be passed to the remote and vice versa. Before, you added the ice candidates from local to your local connection, thats why it didn't work. This why the connectionState was "connecting", and never changed to "connected", as the connection was never fully connected and was still expecting ice candidate exchange.

Comment: Thank god..damn I've been searching straight 4days lol...Thanks very thanks a lot this means a lot to me.

Comment: Took me a while to find it, too -  I'm glad i could help.